# How to diplay accelerometer data on viewController

Tags: swift, accelerometer, viewcontroller

I'm collecting data from gyroscope and accelerometer with a method like this:

```
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(accelQueue, withHandler: accelHandler)
```

the Handler looks like this:

```
func accelHandler (accelerometerData : CMAccelerometerData!, error : NSError!){

    //for saving
    logging.accelerationX = accelerometerData.acceleration.x
    logging.accelerationY = accelerometerData.acceleration.y
    logging.accelerationZ = accelerometerData.acceleration.z

    //for displaying
    accelX.text = (NSString(format: "%.5f", accelerometerData.acceleration.x))
    accelY.text = (NSString(format: "%.5f", accelerometerData.acceleration.y))
    accelZ.text = (NSString(format: "%.5f", accelerometerData.acceleration.z))

}
```

logging.accelerationX is my own variable, accelX.text is of type @IBOutlet weak var accelX: UILabel!. 
The Handler is acting reliable but I do not receive the dataString at the screen in corresponding label.
Someone any proposal?

Comment: Do some debugging. You should add some `println` statements to log to the console. Try logging `accelerometerData` just to prove that the handler is really being called. Try logging `accelX` and `accelX.window` to yourself that this really is a label and that the label is in the interface.

Comment: true, did console output already, as I sad handler is acting properly and I'm receiving frequently data to the console. I will try your proposal logging accelX and accelx.window!Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that the problem is `accelQueue`. You are calling `accelHandler` on this queue. It is a background queue (I'm guessing). But then you are talking to `accelX`, a label in the interface. You must *never* attempt to talk to the interface on a background queue! So you need to step out to the main queue before doing anything like that.

Comment: ah thanks for that info. I had never thought about this. So do you think I should rather use the motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates() Method, thats the one without queue? This queue stuff is confusing myself

Comment: You can do whatever you like but if you use the queue approach you must step out to the main queue if you don't want to bang into serious threading issues. It isn't at all difficult, but it it is necessary.

Comment: The queue approach has advantages and disadvantages. It means you get _all_ the updates. That can be good or bad. With polling thru a timer, you are on the main thread and you can poll less often if that's acceptable.

Comment: Here's an example of the polling approach: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch22p782lyingDown/ch25p1039lyingDown/ViewController.swift That code also illustrates the update queue approach, but you will notice that I use the _main_ thread for my updates! That is exactly so that I don't run into this sort of issue.

Comment: thanks thats cool. I'm going to study queue first, than I try to run your code example.